# What should be done (if anything) about the "How to run [Windows Program] in Wine?" questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There are a lot of questions about how well specific applications run in Wine:

- [How well does Microsoft Office Excel work in Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1686/how-well-does-microsoft-office-excel-work-in-wine)
- [Does Visual Studio Express work well with Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17902/does-visual-studio-express-work-well-with-wine)
- [Running Shaiya in wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46999/running-shaiya-in-wine)
- [Run the bada simulator with Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52670/run-the-bada-simulator-with-wine)
- [What is the best way to run iTunes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2728/what-is-the-best-way-to-run-itunes)
- [Installing Windows Media Player 11 on Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5296/installing-windows-media-player-11-on-wine)
- etc...

It seems like the only valid answer to each of these questions is a link to the appropriate page on the [Wine Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/). Because of this, I am wondering if these questions really belong here.

What does everyone else think?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this is a good example of something that should be a canonical question?

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/

> **Help us build a great library of canonical answers.** If you keep seeing the same form of questions, whether it’s mod_rewrite rules on Server Fault, freezing computers on Super User, or how to use regular expressions to parse HTML, write a great, canonical answer, once and for all. Make it community wiki so that as many other people as possible can make it great. Work really hard on writing something that is clear, concise, and understandable by as wide an audience as possible.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. I'll wait to see what other community  members think of the idea and perhaps discuss its creation.

Comment: The issue is that this one is every application is a little different (and has different dependencies, requires a different version of WINE etc), so that it'd be pretty difficult to write "One Answer For All". But I think the Ask Ubuntu community is up to the challenge.

Comment: @James: Well the problem is that any application-specific information is basically just duplicating content from the Wine AppDB and then we'd need to make sure it was always kept in sync.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison Very true. That case, I suggest that we follow Jeff's advice. My two cents.

Comment: Often times (in recent versions of WINE) it boils down to configuration changes and dll installations. So it might be best to have a one stop shop for most applications and other questions for fringe cases. Overall we should advise moving to native applications where ever possible.

Comment: I've attempted [to start the ball rolling on a canonical question](http://askubuntu.com/q/84903/24694).

Comment: If we had a reasonably short list (say 100) of big canonical QA, a tool to flag a question to point there with only a couple of clicks would be great. For example, a blog page with links to all the canonical QA "ready". I often find that the search of the site is quite lousy (site:askubuntu.com on google is much better).

Comment: And BTW, http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it is probably the mother of all canonical questions...